# Reset View hierarchy iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'd like to add some code to the app delegate that resets the view hierarchy back to the beginning.

My app is basically a demonstration mockup, and I'd like EVERYTIME the app opens that it resets to the first view in the storyboard, and doesn't remember what page the user was on when they closed or 'minimized' the app.

I'm using iOS sdk 8.1, and Xcode 6.

Answer (score 1):

Putting aside that it's actually quite bad user experience - it's very easy to do. You just need to specify that your app doesn't run in the background, and each time user closes app, next time - brand new copy will be launched.

Here is what you need to set in your project properties in Xcode:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I know it's horrible user experience. It's just for a demonstration so the phone can be passed to the next audience member and the experience be reset. That said, I'm not finding that option in the properties, what's the category?

Comment: This doesn't quite work, but it's very close! I still have to 'swipe away' the app by double tapping home button. I want it to reset even when just the home button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

If your'r info.plist **Show raw keys/values** option are enabled, the property is named **UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend** which you can get by right clicking on the empty space of info.plist properties table and selecting **Add Row** option as follows

[image: info.plist screenshot one]

and right after that you will be presented with following option,

[image: info.plist screenshot two]

where you can select second options which is **Application does not run in the background**.

Selecting the mentioned property and setting it to **YES**, the app opt out of background mode and it cycles between the not-running, inactive, and active states and never enters the background or suspended states and moved back to the not-running state. In other words, iOS will not preserved any states which allows the app to run as fresh on next launch.